# ssh ask the remote to run a command or open a Python script(on raspberry)

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi3

I want to use the master to send a information or command to remote slave, like 'hey! open the python script now!', and the slave will open the exact python script just on the slave, the master only send the opening command.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following link on writing a good question and edit accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh user@host 'python path/2/your/script.py'
```